# A bash/wget script runs from command line but fails to run under launchd - output files not written

Tags: macos, bash, wget, launchd

I am having a terrible time getting a bash script that uses wget to run as a launchd job.  The script is designed to automate downloading of the daily New York Times crossword puzzle.  Note that you need a subscription (USERNAME and PASSWORD) to make this work.

The original script (which lives at http://web.mit.edu/lizdenys/Public/crossword) works great and is an impressive and educational example of bash scripting (for me at least).  Here is the orignal.  I modified it for my use by including user and pass and commenting out the steps to download anything but the PDF version (I like pencil and paper).

-=-=-=-=-=-=begin bash script-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
#!/bin/bash

# crossword,
# a wget-based nytimes crossword downloader

# Liz A. Denys (liz@lizdenys.com)
# Last updated on May 13, 2015

# This script downloads today's New York Times daily crossword. To
# use, you must change the email and password information below so
# that it corresponds to your premium New York Times account.

# Get the current date.
puzdate=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
pdfdate=`date "+%b%d%y"`

# Get the login page.
wget --no-check-certificate https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login \
  -O login.html &>/dev/null

# Scrape token and expires values so wget can auth.
token=`grep token login.html | sed -e 's/^.*value="\([0-9a-f]\+\)".*$/\1/'`
expires=`grep expires login.html | sed -e 's/^.*value="\([0-9a-f]\+\)".*$/\1/'`

# Log in with password. Note: this does not work without replacing
# username and password information.
wget --post-data \
  "userid=USERNAME%40DOMAIN.COM&password=PASSWORDVALUE&is_continue=false&remember=true&token=$token&expires=$expires" \
  --save-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate \
  -O /dev/null https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login &>/dev/null

# Download puzzle in .pdf and .puz formats.
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt \
 http://www.nytimes.com/svc/crosswords/v2/puzzle/print/$pdfdate.pdf \
  &>/dev/null
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt \
  http://www.nytimes.com/svc/crosswords/v2/puzzle/daily-$puzdate.puz \
  &>/dev/null

# Clean up workspace.
rm cookies.txt
rm login.html
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=end bash script-=-=-=-=-=-=

I made the required edit and the script ran from the command line ON THE FIRST ATTEMPT!

Since I don't have internet access every day and since (as far as I know) puzzles are no longer available the day after they appear, I decided that I would automate the job to run every day.  I've used cron (for incremental backups on a Sparcstation) with no problems what so ever (using make to select files to write to tape - that reveals my vintage), but NO, Apple wants me to use launchd.  I'm always happy to learn something new and useful so my task was to learn enough about launchd and plists to perform this extremely simple job.  Not so!!

Here is one of many plists that failed:

-=-=-=-=-=-=begin .plist file-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.me.nytxwd</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/me/Documents/misc/nytimes_xword/nytimes_puzzle_dl4.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Documents/misc/nytimes_xword/err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Documents/misc/nytimes_xword/tmp</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Documents/misc/nytimes_xword/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=end .plist file-=-=-=-=-=-=

Here are my observations:

-script runs fine from the command line (with necessary mods)
-script fails when run from launchd (exit 1) as a per-user job (~/Library/LaunchAgents/).  System log reveals that the  file that grep looks for and contains the two essential bits of data are never written to the target directory ("grep token login.html - no such file").

I originally tried to run as a StartCalendarInterval job at 0900 every day but when that failed, I switched over to OnDemand using launchctl load/unload for debugging.  Somethings that I tried:

Specifying paths in plist (error, out, working directory) - no help

Changing ownership and permissions on the target directory. - no help

Changing paths in the script to be absolute (no ~, no $HOME, no ., no relative). - no help
https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login \
  -O /Users/me/Documents/misc/nytimes_xword/login.html &>/dev/null>

I've read the man pages for launchd, launchctl, launchd.plist without any epiphanies.

I've googled every combination of launchd/bash/wget and learned somethings but still no success.

I ran an example provided by 
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.06/launchd/index.html
and it worked!!  However, it didn't illustrate how to write and read a text file to a user directory.

Mac OS X 10.5.8 if that matters.

I know that this is quite a bit longer than the typical question posed here but I wanted to avoid the obvious "did you try this" questions.

I'm assuming that a guru is going to reveal the mojo of launchd with a simple and obvious solution.  Well, at least I'll move on to launchd step 2.

Thanks,
jlh

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I solved it using `curl` instead.

`wget http://opendata-download-metobs.smhi.se/api/version/1.0/parameter/2/station/178970/period/corrected-archive/data.csv`

`curl -C - -o data.csv http://opendata-download-metobs.smhi.se/api/version/1.0/parameter/2/station/178970/period/corrected-archive/data.csv`

The first line worked for me in the terminal but I had to use the second in my scripted version. One good thing is that `curl` allowed me to specify a file name, which `wget` had refused to do.